# Windows command promt

Tags: windows, cmd

I was asked a question recently in an interview. Can some please help with this

Q: A user types a URL in the browser and the screen turns white and you have access to command prompt what would you do?

Comment: How is this related to programming, which is what SO is about?

Comment: If the interview for a position within the IT department, I'd respond by asking the interviewer for more information because they've not provided sufficient information for me to diagnose an issue. If the interviewer doesn't have that information I'd tell them that I'd ask the end user for it  before I touch anything. If the interview was not for a position within the IT department, I would answer by telling the interviewer that I'd follow the advice provided within the company guidelines, *probably contact the IT helpdesk*.

Answer (score 0):

● First, it checks the browser cache.

● Second, the browser checks the OS cache.

● Third, it checks the router cache. If it’s not found on your computer.

You can also Press **ctrl+shift+n** then a black screen will open you can type the url.